# Keep a particlesystems transform and cone radius relative to its parent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a "Lift". While being in the game, you walk into the particle system and get moved up in the air (on y).

So the particle system is a child of the cube / the lift. So when scaling the cube, I don't want to change the settings of the particle system. It should scale itself on its own.

When the cube got the y position on 5 and a height / scaling on y of 10, the particle system should place itself down at the bottom.

As you can see, I want it being full automatic.

So, when heading into the code I got this

```
[SerializeField]
ParticleSystem liftParticles;

private void Start()
{
    Vector3 objectScale = transform.localScale; // cube scaling

    Vector3 particlePos = liftParticles.transform.position; // temp position
    particlePos.y = (particlePos.y - objectScale.y) / 2; // move down on y
    liftParticles.transform.position = particlePos; // set particle position

    float transformScalingX = objectScale.x; // x scaling of the cube
    float transformScalingZ = objectScale.z; // z scaling of the cube

    var shape = liftParticles.shape; // set the cone radius now
    shape.radius = transformScalingX > transformScalingZ ? transformScalingX : transformScalingZ;
    liftParticles.shape = shape;
}
```

I want to go with the following example as mentioned above..

The cube got a scaling of (3,10,3) and its position is (0,5,0)

my current calculation `particlePos.y` returns a value of -0,75 **but** it has to be -0,5.

So do I have an error in my code? (yes obviously I do ...)

The second problem is, how do I change the radius of the particlesystem? When trying to reference the radius of the cone, it says I can't change it, it is readonly.

Is it? I hope I can change this somehow ...

**Edit:**

Obviously, the particlesystem just has to be always on -0,5f on y when having a scaling of (1,1,1). No need for a calculation anymore.

But I still need to change the radius of the shape and set the lifetime of the particles relative to the height of the lift. Means

```
private void Start()
{
    Vector3 liftScale = transform.localScale; // Liftscaling

    var shape = liftParticles.shape; // temp shape
    shape.radius = liftScale.x > liftScale.z ? liftScale.x : liftScale.z; // set radius
    liftParticles.shape = shape; // assign the temp shape to the real shape

    liftParticles.main.startLifetime = ; // set the liftetime of the particles relative to its parent height on y 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you made the particle system child of the lift (a cube) so it can move together. In case you just want that both of them move together, but they scale independently, you should consider to use an Empty GameObject as a parent.

You can placed this Empty GameObject in the middle of the Cube (your lift) and then make the lift and the particle filter children of that Empty GameObject. Then move the Empty GameObject instead of the lift, and the children will move as well.

About modifying the radio, try this script

```
GameObject myParticleGenerator;

ParticleSystem.ShapeModule pShape;

pShape = yParticleGenerator.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().shape;

pShape.radius = 4.0f;
```